# Theme execution flow

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, xml

I would like to know theme execution flow of Magento 2.

I select a theme name 'A' and try to visit a page. Then I change the theme to 'B' and try to visit that same page. Which execution flow the themes will follow ? What will change in this theme changing situation ?